# In Stripe, what Webhook is fired when a subscription expires?

Tags: stripe-payments

When a subscription "naturally" ends which webhook is sent by Stripe?

By "naturally", I mean:

- not manually cancelled by the user, and
- not deleted by an admin,

Example 1: Customer card expires, and attempts to re-charge fail and the subscription is stopped

Example 2: The subscription is set to "not renew"

Possible webhooks:

1. `customer.subscription.updated` with `cancel_at=now` ? (this occurs when user manually cancels)
2. `customer.subscription.deleted` ? (this occurs when admin deletes subscription)

(I applied for their Test Clock Beta : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test_clocks which would allow me to fast forward time, but haven't got access yet)

Comment: It's the latter, `customer.subscription.deleted`

Comment: Thanks @karllekko . I reached out to Customer Support at the same time and they are saying "The customer.subscription.deleted event will be send only if such action is done via dashboard or from side of your customer via Customer Portal.", but they couldn't provide me a webhook that is actually fired during that phase. So you are probably correct: do you know where in the docs it mentions it?

Comment: That information is wrong. I am correct. It's not directly mentioned in any docs I can find but I've used Stripe's API for years and that's how it works.

Comment: I like that confidence! Thanks @karllekko , feel free to add it as an answer and I will mark it correct

Answer (score 3):

It should be `customer.subscription.deleted`

> Stripe sends a customer.subscription.deleted event when a customer’s subscription is canceled immediately. If the customer.subscription.deleted event’s request property isn’t null, that indicates the cancellation was made by your request (as opposed to automatically based upon your subscription settings).
> If you instead cancel a subscription at the end of the billing period (that is, by setting cancel_at_period_end to true), a customer.subscription.updated event is immediately triggered. That event reflects the change in the subscription’s cancel_at_period_end value. When the subscription is actually canceled at the end of the period, a customer.subscription.deleted event then occurs.

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/cancel#events

Answer (score -1):

Afaik, `customer.subscription.deleted` triggers only when the subscription is cancelled not over.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is in contradiction with @karllekko above